# Complex conjugate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, complex-numbers

I can't find the complex conjugate of the following function: 
$$Ca^{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{2a\pi} \exp \Big(\frac{-(2am + 2\hbar it)mx^2}{(2am+2\hbar it)^2}\Big) \sqrt{\frac{m}{2a\pi m + 2\hbar \pi it}}.$$

I know how to find a complex conjugate for more basic complex numbers. Do I just put a minus sign in front of every term with an $i$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Why don't you simplify it to usual (rectangular) form?

Comment: Indeed it's actually a mathematics question, but this equation is my solution of the schrödinger equation of my specific problem. I'm quite new to this website, so I will remember your advice. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rules: 
1) The conjugate of a sum is the sum of the conjugates.
2) The conjugate of a product is the product of the conjugates.
3) The conjugate of a quotient is the quotient of the conjugates.
4) The exponential of the conjugate is the conjugate of the exponential.

You can find this laws in [Complex conjugate in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 \bar C = C \\
\overline { \sqrt a } = \sqrt a \\
 \overline {\sqrt{2a\pi}} =  \sqrt{2a\pi} \\
\overline {-(2am + 2\hbar it)mx^2} = {-(2am - 2\hbar it)mx^2} \\ 
\overline {(2am+2\hbar it)^2} = {(2am-2\hbar it)^2} \\
\overline {\Big(\frac{-(2am + 2\hbar it)mx^2}{(2am+2\hbar it)^2}\Big)} = \Big(\frac{-(2am - 2\hbar it)mx^2}{(2am-2\hbar it)^2}\Big) \\
\overline {\exp \Big(\frac{-(2am + 2\hbar it)mx^2}{(2am+2\hbar it)^2}\Big)} =  \exp \Big(\frac{-(2am - 2\hbar it)mx^2}{(2am-2\hbar it)^2}\Big) \\
\overline {\sqrt{\frac{m}{2a\pi m + 2\hbar \pi it}}} = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2a\pi m - 2\hbar \pi it}}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: Indeed somehow by summing up the basic rules, I have a much clearer vision on how to approach the problem. So just solving step by step should bring me to a solution.

Comment: The fact that the only answer with explicit formulae in it uses overbars instead of stars for complex conjugates is probably the strongest evidence that this question belongs on maths SE instead of the physics site.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't just put a minus before every $i$.

I'd suggest trying Wolfram Alpha, or try and simplify the expression.

Remember that for quotients, you can multiply and divide the quotient by the conjugate of the denominator, and so you'll get the squared norm of it as the new denominator: [see this for more info](http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/complex/dividing/dividing_complex.html)

Again, trying to use Wolfram Alpha or some other program is quicker.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why I can't   post at the  moment comments with  equations .

Comment: @Frobenius Do you allow me to keep the example you gave and give you credit?

Comment: Oh, NO. I edit your answer temporarely, since I can't comment with equations. Anyway forget and ignore my edit and comments

Comment: @Frobenius ok then

Comment: I want to believe that I didn't damage your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70618/discussion-between-itamarg3-and-frobenius).